# Как в php переконвертировать jpg в png, заменяя белый фон прозрачным? (transparent)

Tags: php, изображения

Пользуюсь простым решением конвертирования

```
imagepng(imagecreatefromstring($file1, $file2);
```

Фон остаётся белым.

Comment: А этот код работает? Скобка не закрыта

Comment: а почему он должен стать прозрачным?

Comment: Никак. Точнее в jpeg используется довольно сложный алгоритм сжатия по этому даже если в сохраните чисто белую картинку вы скорее всего не найдёте там даже 2 пикселей белого цвета стоящих рядом. По этому вам прийдется писать довольно сложный алгоритм что бы дать компьютеру понять что такое в вашем понимании белый цвет.